# Publish Visual Studio software with MySql database file (XAMPP)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xampp

I finished a project in Visual Studio and I want to publish it into an executable file including the MySql database file in Xampp.

Is there a way to create a setup file for my program including the MySql database file without installing Xampp on another computer that isn't connected to a network?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use the  [Visual Studio Installer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects)  extension to author an installer for your exe.

Then use the  [DotNetInstaller](http://dblock.github.io/dotnetinstaller/)  to package all of your items together?